# Convert dxf to bmp write on python

Tags: python

Do you know good library (write on python) for converting dxf files to bmp?
I have a folder with "filename_number" dxf files.
I want read it and convert it to bmp. Also I want keep file's dimension size.

Comment: A `DXF` file is not measured in pixels. What do you mean by keeping the dimentions?

Comment: I know. I mean each line to convert in pixel. I have to find the biggest line to set a width and height for bmp file.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer from [here](http://pydoc.net/Python/Goulib/1.5.0/Goulib.dxf2img/):

```
import StringIO, base64, logging, operator

import dxfgrabber
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont #PIL

from homcoord import *

def rint(x):return int(round(x))

class BBox:
    """bounding box"""
    def __init__(self,pt1=None,pt2=None):
        self._corner1=None
        self._corner2=None
        if pt1: self+=pt1
        if pt2: self+=pt2

    def __iadd__(self,pt):
        if isinstance(pt,BBox):
            self+=pt._corner1
            self+=pt._corner2
        else:
            if not self._corner1:
                self._corner1=pt
            else:
                self._corner1=Pt(map(min,zip(self._corner1.xy,pt.xy)))
            if not self._corner2:
                self._corner2=pt
            else:
                self._corner2=Pt(map(max,zip(self._corner2.xy,pt.xy)))
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return "BBox(%s,%s)"%(self._corner1,self._corner2)

    def __call__(self):
        """:return: list of flatten corners"""
        l=list(self._corner1.xy)
        l.extend(list(self._corner2.xy))
        return l

    def size(self):
        """:return: Pt with xy sizes"""
        return self._corner2-self._corner1

    def center(self):
        """:return: Pt center"""
        res=self._corner2+self._corner1
        return res/2

    def trans(self,trans):
        """
        :param trans: Xform
        :return: BBox = self transformed by trans
        """
        return BBox(trans(self._corner1),trans(self._corner2))

def cbox(c,r):
    """ bounding box of a circle
    :param c: Pt center
    :param r: float radius
    :return: BBox
    """
    rr=Pt(r,r)
    return BBox(c+rr,c-rr)

def Trans(scale=1, offset=[0,0], rotation=0):
    res=Xform([[scale,0,offset[0]],[0,scale,offset[1]],[0,0,1]])
    if rotation:
        res=Xrotate(rotation*pi/180.)*res
    return res

class DXF:
    def __init__(self, file, layers=None, ignore=[]):
        """reads a .dxf file
        :param file: string path to .dxf file to read
        :param layers: list or dictionary of layers to handle. Empty = all layers
        :param ignore: list of strings of entity types to ignore
        """
        self.dxf=dxfgrabber.readfile(file)
        self.layers=layers
        self.ignore=ignore

    def entities(self,ent=None):
        """iterator over dxf or block entities"""
        if not ent:
            ent=self.dxf.entities
        for e in ent:
            if self.layers and e.layer not in self.layers:
                continue
            elif e.dxftype in self.ignore:
                continue
            else: 
                yield e

    def bbox(self):
        """:return: :class:BBox dwg enclosing bounding box"""
        box=BBox()
        for e in self.entities():
            if e.dxftype=='LINE':
                box+=Pt(e.start[:2])
                box+=Pt(e.end[:2])
            elif e.dxftype == 'CIRCLE':
                box+=cbox(Pt(e.center[:2]),e.radius)
            elif e.dxftype == 'ARC':
                c=Pt(e.center[:2])
                a=e.endangle-e.startangle
                if a>0:
                    start=e.startangle
                else: #arc goes clockwise (step will be negative)
                    start=e.endangle
                n=rint(abs(a)/10.) # number of points each 10Â° approximately
                n=max(n,1)
                step=a/n #angle between 2 points, might be negative
                for i in range(n+1):
                    box+=c.radial(e.radius,radians(start+i*step))
            elif e.dxftype=='POLYLINE':
                for v in e.vertices:
                    box+=Pt(v.location[:2])
            elif e.dxftype=='BLOCK': 
                pass #TODO ...
            elif e.dxftype in ['TEXT','INSERT']:
                box+=Pt(e.insert[:2])
            else:
                logging.warning('Unknown entity %s'%e)
        return box

    def _draw(self,draw,entities,trans,pen="black"):
        for e in entities:
            if e.dxftype=='LINE':
                b=list(trans(Pt(e.start[:2])).xy)
                b.extend(list(trans(Pt(e.end[:2])).xy))
                draw.line(b,fill=pen)
            elif e.dxftype=='CIRCLE':
                b=cbox(Pt(e.center[:2]),e.radius)
                b=b.trans(trans)
                draw.ellipse(b(),outline=pen)
            elif e.dxftype=='ARC':
                c=Pt(e.center[:2])
                b=cbox(c,e.radius)
                b=b.trans(trans)
                b=map(rint,b())
                startangle=degrees(trans.angle(radians(e.startangle)))
                endangle=degrees(trans.angle(radians(e.endangle)))
                startangle,endangle=endangle,startangle #swap start/end because of Y symmetry
                draw.arc(b,int(startangle),int(endangle),fill=pen)
            elif e.dxftype=='POLYLINE':
                b=[]
                for v in e.vertices:
                    b.extend(list(trans(Pt(v.location[:2])).xy))
                draw.line(b,fill=pen)
            elif e.dxftype=='TEXT':
                h=e.height*trans.mag()
                pt=Pt(e.insert[:2])+Pt(0,e.height) #ACAD places texts by top left point...
                font=None
                try:
                    font = ImageFont.truetype("c:/windows/fonts/Courier New.ttf", rint(h))
                except:
                    pass
                if not font:
                    h=h*1.4 #magic factor ...
                    fh=[8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,36,40,48,60]
                    i,h=min(enumerate(fh), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-h)) #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706041/finding-index-of-an-item-closest-to-the-value-in-a-list-thats-not-entirely-sort
                    import os
                    path=os.path.realpath(__file__)
                    path=os.path.dirname(path)
                    font = ImageFont.load(path+'\\base_pil\\72\\Courier New_%s_72.pil'%h)
                draw.text(trans(pt).xy,e.text,font=font,fill=pen) 
            elif e.dxftype=='INSERT': 
                t2=Trans(1,e.insert,e.rotation).compose(trans)

                self._draw(draw,self.entities(self.dxf.blocks[e.name]._entities),t2,pen)
            elif e.dxftype=='BLOCK': 
                pass # block definition is automatically stored in dxf.blocks dictionary
            else:
                logging.warning('Unknown entity %s'%e)

    def img(self,size=[256,256],back="white",pen="black",border=5,antialias=1):
        """:result: :class:`PIL:Image` rasterized image"""
        box=self.bbox()
        from Goulib.math2 import product
        if not product(box.size().xy): # either x or y ==0
            return None

        s=map(operator.div,[float(x-border)*antialias if x else 1E9 for x in size ],box.size().xy)
        trans=Trans(scale=min(s))
        size=trans(box.size())+Pt(2*antialias*border,2*antialias*border) #add borders as an offset
        offset=size/2-trans(box.center()) #offset in pixel coordinates
        trans=trans*Trans(offset=offset.xy)
        trans=trans*Xscale(1,-1) #invert y axis
        trans=trans*Xlate(0,size.y) #origin is lower left corner

        img = Image.new("RGB", map(rint,size.xy), back)
        self._draw(ImageDraw.Draw(img), self.entities(), trans, pen)
        if antialias>1:
            size=size/antialias
            img=img.resize(map(rint,size.xy), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        return img

def img2base64(img,fmt='PNG'):
    """
    :param img: :class:`PIL:Image`
    :result: string base64 encoded image content in specified format
    :see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348442/django-how-do-i-display-a-pil-image-object-in-a-template
    """
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(output, fmt)
    output.seek(0)
    output_s = output.read()
    return base64.b64encode(output_s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dxf=DXF("..\\tests\\FERRO_01.DXF")
    img=dxf.img(size=[1280,None],border=50)
    print img2base64(img)
    img.save('..\\tests\\out.png')
```

Comment: I tried that but I had troubles with this library  "homcoord". I use Mac OSX Yosemite. Actually this is good suggestion. Maybe I have to read more carefully about this library.

Comment: take a look at: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/contrib.html/lang/python/examples/meanball/homcoord.py

Comment: Thanks. I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

1. extract all the details you need using ezdxf library.
2. using matplotlib library plot them as graph using matplotlib commands.
3. save the file as you need using same matplotlib library.